# Not able to view specific information. Click events. Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've been able to collect a list of companies which are able to be clicked to reveal company data. There are 10 companies total. The problem is, when I click one link to view the data for that specific company, all of the data (for all 10 companies) appear.

Here's a picture of my problem. [Click here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F17h7.png) As you can see, *Topsome* was clicked, but all the information was shown.

Here is the javascript code I'm using.

This function `(findCompanies.js)` collects the list of companies.

```
function findCompanies()
{
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      var companies = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
      var list = "<p>There are totally "+companies.totalResults+" companies of which the 10 first are listed here.</p>";
      for (i=0;i<10;i++)
      {
      company = companies.results[i].name;
      list = list + "<a href='#/' onclick='findCompanyData(company);'>"+company + "</a><br/>";
      }
      document.getElementById("ansver").innerHTML = list;
    }
  }
  url = "http://avoindata.prh.fi:80/tr/v1?totalResults=true&maxResults=10&resultsFrom=0&companyRegistrationFrom="+document.input.start.value+"&companyRegistrationTo="+document.input.end.value;
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

This function provides the details of the companies.

```
function findCompanyData(company)
{
  var xhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp2.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp2.readyState == 4 && xhttp2.status == 200) {
      var companydata = JSON.parse(xhttp2.responseText);
      var list = "<h6>Company Information: </h6>";
      for (i=0;i<10;i++)
      {            
       var name = "<p>Company Name: "+companydata.results[i].name +" </p>";
       var companyId = "<p>Company ID#: "+companydata.results[i].businessId +" </p>"; 
       var registrationDate = "<p>Registration Date: "+companydata.results[i].registrationDate +" </p>";
       var companyType = "<p>Company Type: "+companydata.results[i].companyForm +" </p>";

       list = list + name + companyId + registrationDate + companyType;   

      }
     document.getElementById("companydata").innerHTML = list;
    }
  }
  url = "http://avoindata.prh.fi:80/tr/v1?totalResults=true&maxResults=10&resultsFrom=0&companyRegistrationFrom="+document.input.start.value+"&companyRegistrationTo="+document.input.end.value;
  xhttp2.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp2.send();
}
```

Any advice or recommendations? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
function findCompanies()
{
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      var companies = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
      var list = "<p>There are totally "+companies.totalResults+" companies of which the 10 first are listed here.</p>";
      for (i=0;i<10;i++)
      {
      company = companies.results[i].name;  // Without quotes, 'company' will be treated as a var
      company = '"'+company+'"';            // ADDED THIS LINE to quote the company
      list = list + "<a href='#/' onclick='findCompanyData("+company+");'>"+company + "</a><br/>";
      }
      document.getElementById("ansver").innerHTML = list;
    }
  }
  url = "http://avoindata.prh.fi:80/tr/v1?totalResults=true&maxResults=10&resultsFrom=0&companyRegistrationFrom="+document.input.start.value+"&companyRegistrationTo="+document.input.end.value;
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

And second function

```
function findCompanyData(company)
{
  var xhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp2.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp2.readyState == 4 && xhttp2.status == 200) {
      var companydata = JSON.parse(xhttp2.responseText);
      var list = "<h6>Company Information: </h6>";
      for (i=0;i<10;i++)
      {
          // Only add info to be shown if this was the company clicked.
          if (companydata.results[i].name === company) {    // ADDED THIS LINE
              var name = "<p>Company Name: "+companydata.results[i].name +" </p>";
              var companyId = "<p>Company ID#: "+companydata.results[i].businessId +" </p>"; 
              var registrationDate = "<p>Registration Date: "+companydata.results[i].registrationDate +" </p>";
              var companyType = "<p>Company Type: "+companydata.results[i].companyForm +" </p>";

              list = list + name + companyId + registrationDate + companyType;   
          }
      }
     document.getElementById("companydata").innerHTML = list;
    }
  }
  url = "http://avoindata.prh.fi:80/tr/v1?totalResults=true&maxResults=10&resultsFrom=0&companyRegistrationFrom="+document.input.start.value+"&companyRegistrationTo="+document.input.end.value;
  xhttp2.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp2.send();
}
```

Comment: Replace list = list + "<a href='#/' onclick='findCompanyData("+company+");'>"+company + "</a><br/>";    WITH THIS list = list + "<a href='#/' onclick='findCompanyData('"+company+"');'>"+company + "</a><br/>";

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I did as you suggested and still no results. I inspected and saw the error "Unexpected Token". It then listed this line `(function(event){findCompanies();
})`

Comment: Looking at your posted code I can't see what's different unless I study it thoroughly.  Explain what was wrong, and where and how you fixed it. An upvote (tooltip) says "This answer is useful" — a code dump is not "useful"; people who find this Q & A should learn something from it.

Comment: Sure Stephen, you are right. In first method I try to pass company name string to method parameter. In second method I filter data and select only the data that contain company name. I fixed the code. I hope it work!

Comment: Thanks for your help! It works! I don't know why it behaves differently now, but it's great! Thanks for your help! I sincerely appreciate it!! :D